# Extra page on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports and when I print a report from my end it is not printing an extra page, but when the customer tries printing it prints an extra page on some of the reports. "New Page After" is checked and greyed out and it won't let me click X-2, but I don't think that is the issue. Very frustrating that I cannot recreate the issue to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the next suspect is record inflation due to table joins. In other words, a record that you believe is joined to only a single record in another table is actually joining to 2 records, causing a repeat of the information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because the client's printer forces larger page margins, causing content on the right to spill to a next page.

So change your report design to have bigger page margins.

hth.

Comment: I just found out that its not printing a blank page on the new page. When the customer prints the report, it is printing the same information as the first page. So I don't believe it is a margin issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check Design and make sure everything in on the white paper
Also check the header and footer for  groups and ensure you don't have anything unnecessary Check Page footer section so ensure there is not any thing on the grey section
Suppress any unwanted header or footer section

Go to file and page set up and make sure you are using the correct size of the paper and you have the same paper installed on the printer.
Change the orientation to landscape to check if that help.
Also as MilletSoftware mentioned check of margins